# Angular Cli set the path for font files

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-cli

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC application that comprises of several different Angular apps.  On one of my apps I want to use Angular router so I have set the base path to the location of my asp.net core view instead of the output directory.

```
"outDir": "wwwroot/spa/task",
```

The asp.net route to the app is `example.com/Task`.  On this page I want to add a router outlet.  In the view code in order for it to correcty route pages I have set the base href to match my asp.net route:

```
<base href="/Task">
```

and I point the scripts to the output folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/spa/task/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/spa/task/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/spa/task/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/spa/task/font-awesome.min.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/spa/task/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/spa/task/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Everything loads fine and works except the font's are being linked to relatively from the initial page so I get these errors:

[image]

How do I set Angular CLI so it is looking for these files in the right location?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I needed to set webpack public path variable.  Luckily this has been patched in recently, I just had to add this to config:

```
"deployUrl": "/spa/task/"
```